# sum column table filter by data

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In this table :

```
        Total           Data 
     -----------------------------
         1            2013-07-10 16:37:29.573
        1,5           2013-07-10 16:38:29.573
        0,75          2013-07-10 16:39:29.573
        1,99          2013-07-10 16:40:29.573
```

i been write this ms-sql procedure :

```
     ALTER proc [dbo].[empcx](@caixa int,@inicio datetime)as
     select sum(total) ttotal from alteraca 
     where (DATA >= @inicio AND DATA <= @inicio) and caixa=@caixa and pedido <>0
```

but i call i this way :

```
     empcx 6 , '11/07/2013'
```

and only returns null  , need a cast or something???
i gonna call this procedure in C# with this parameter

```
     label4.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: `DATA >= @inicio AND DATA <= @inicio`  =  `DATA = @inicio`

Comment: Yeah, as @mr.Reband stated, your where clause is filtering out all values except those where DATA = '@inicio'.  What were you trying to accomplish in your where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of parameter @inicio is 2013-07-11 0:00:00.000;

but in the procedure you are comparing this value with dates containing a time component, eg 2013-07-10 16:37:29.573

since you are using (DATA >= @inicio AND DATA <= @inicio), which as Mr Reband comments above is the same as (DATA = @inicio), no rows are matched, and thus Null is returned.

try

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[empcx](@caixa int,@inicio datetime)as
     select sum(total) ttotal from alteraca 
     where (Convert(varchar(10),DATA,101) = Convert(varchar(10),@inicio,101))
       and caixa=@caixa and pedido <>0
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mr. Bingham's answer, but I'd use a slightly different method to do the comparison:

```
 ALTER proc [dbo].[empcx](
   @caixa int,
   @inicio datetime
 )
 as
 select sum(total) ttotal 
 from   alteraca 
 where  (DATA >= @inicio AND DATA < DATEADD(dd, 1, @inicio)) 
   and  caixa=@caixa 
   and  pedido <>0
```

I haven't run tests, but I believe this would be faster.

Also, if your values of `total` are really what you show them as - comma-separated strings of numbers - your query will crash when you actually start returning records.  A comma-separated string cannot have SUM applied to it, since it can't be parsed into a single number.

Comment: Interesting variation. I'll look into it sometime